# I want to Add product quantity increment like 2pkt,4pkt and 8pkt and i also want to discount

Tags: magento

I'm working on an eCommerce website using `Magento`.

I want to add product quantity increments like 2pkt, 4pkt. I would also like to associate discounts with these quantities such as 2pkt with 7%, 4pkt with 10%, and 8pkt with 15% discount.

I do not know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Trying to make it more understandable

Comment: see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoMShnuypfc  I want to tier quantity in dropdown to individual priduct like 1 product is 2,4,8 and other product like 3,6,12